# Misplaced \omit in table

Tags: tables

Hi I'm new to Latex and have a table that keeps erroring out with a Misplaced \omit error. Can someone help me identify what the issue is? The code is below. Thank you

```
\begin{table}
 \TABLE
{Return Lag and Return Rate Descriptive Statistics for Electronics Dataset \label{tab:testa}}
{\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline
\up \down  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Return Rate} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Return Lag} & Total Observations \\ \cline{2-8}
\up \down \multicolumn{1}{c}{Category} & Average & Std. Dev. & Coeff. of Var. & Average & Std. Dev. & Coeff. of Var. \\ \hline
\up Audio & 12\%  & 0.32  & 2.76  & 12.9  & 20.0  & 1.6 &  11,367 \\
    Auto Parts & 14\%  & 0.35  & 2.44  & 21.9  & 54.1  & 2.5  &  7,211 \\
    Cable & 11\%  & 0.31  & 2.91  & 10.9  & 19.8  & 1.8  &  9,398 \\
    Computer & 11\%  & 0.31  & 2.90  & 11.1  & 23.0  & 2.1 & 21,811  \\
    Imaging & 11\%  & 0.31  & 2.92  & 11.8  & 19.9  & 1.7 & 7,823   \\
    Mobile Phone & 16\%  & 0.37  & 2.27  & 28.9  & 74.4  & 2.6  &  3,126 \\
    Phone  & 14\%  & 0.35  & 2.47  & 16.1  & 30.6  & 1.9 & 5,777 \\
    TV    & 8\%   & 0.28  & 3.28  & 11.3  & 21.5  & 1.9 &  9,413  \\
    TV Box & 14\%  & 0.34  & 2.52  & 14.7  & 28.5  & 1.9 & 9,799 \\
\down   \textbf{Sample Average} & \textbf{12\%} & \textbf{0.33} & \textbf{2.72} & \textbf{15.5} & \textbf{32.4} & \textbf{2.0} & \textbf{1,201.05} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
{}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: also unrelated to the error  you should probably not be using `c` columns for  numeric columns, use `r` or a decimal aligned column from `dcolumn` or `siunitx` package, so the digits line up correctly. What are `\TABLE`, `\up`, `\down` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have text in the same cell as a `\multicolumn`.  Move this text inside, i.e. transform

```
\up \down \multicolumn{1}{c}{Category}
```

into

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\up \down Category}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\up{?}
\newcommand\down{??}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline
  \up \down                              & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Return Rate} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Return Lag} & Total Observations                                                                \\ \cline{2-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\up \down Category} & Average                         & Std. Dev.                      & Coeff. of Var. & Average       & Std. Dev.     & Coeff. of Var.                   \\ \hline
  \up Audio                              & 12\%                            & 0.32                           & 2.76           & 12.9          & 20.0          & 1.6          & 11,367            \\
  Auto Parts                             & 14\%                            & 0.35                           & 2.44           & 21.9          & 54.1          & 2.5          & 7,211             \\
  Cable                                  & 11\%                            & 0.31                           & 2.91           & 10.9          & 19.8          & 1.8          & 9,398             \\
  Computer                               & 11\%                            & 0.31                           & 2.90           & 11.1          & 23.0          & 2.1          & 21,811            \\
  Imaging                                & 11\%                            & 0.31                           & 2.92           & 11.8          & 19.9          & 1.7          & 7,823             \\
  Mobile Phone                           & 16\%                            & 0.37                           & 2.27           & 28.9          & 74.4          & 2.6          & 3,126             \\
  Phone                                  & 14\%                            & 0.35                           & 2.47           & 16.1          & 30.6          & 1.9          & 5,777             \\
  TV                                     & 8\%                             & 0.28                           & 3.28           & 11.3          & 21.5          & 1.9          & 9,413             \\
  TV Box                                 & 14\%                            & 0.34                           & 2.52           & 14.7          & 28.5          & 1.9          & 9,799             \\
  \down   \textbf{Sample Average}        & \textbf{12\%}                   & \textbf{0.33}                  & \textbf{2.72}  & \textbf{15.5} & \textbf{32.4} & \textbf{2.0} & \textbf{1,201.05} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```